# gcc asks to use -std=c++11 even if I'm already using it

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, compiler-errors, compilation

I'm trying to compile the code provided in [this](http://alchemy.cs.washington.edu/papers/kok08/) page.  Here's the gcc command I am using :

```
$HOME/gcc-6.3.0/bin/g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -ansi -g -Wno-deprecated -I./util -finline-limit=100000 -c -o type.o type.cpp
```

I get the following errors and warnings :

```
In file included from ~/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/cstdint:35:0,
                 from cluster.h:6,
                 from type.h:7,
                 from type.cpp:1:
~/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: erreur : #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support \
  ^~~~~
In file included from type.cpp:2:0:
relation.h: Dans la fonction membre « int Relation::getState(const CombNode* const&, const CombNode* const&, const int&, const bool&) »:
relation.h:1172:7: attention : this « if » clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
       if (cmp < 0)  return STATE_N0_BEFORE_N1;
       ^~
relation.h:1173:21: note : ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the « if »
                     return STATE_N0_AFTER_N1;
                     ^~~~~~
relation.h:1178:7: attention : this « if » clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
       if (cmp < 0)  return STATE_N0_AFTER_N1;
       ^~
relation.h:1179:21: note : ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the « if »
                     return STATE_N0_BEFORE_N1;
                     ^~~~~~
makefile:26 : la recette pour la cible « type.o » a échouée
make: *** [type.o] Erreur 1
```

What I don't understand is that I am using the option -std=c++11, but I still get "This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard". I tried -std=gnu++11 as suggested by the error message but this didn't change gcc output.

Answer (score 6):

Take out the `-ansi` switch. If you provide multiple version switches then the latest one overrules the earlier ones.

Comment: "ansi" refers to c90 right ? I think that the code requires C++11. I tried removing the option "-ansi", but I got more errors (e.g `./util/hashint.h:13:50: erreur : reference to "hash" is ambiguous size_t operator()(const int& i) const { return hash<int>()(i); }`)

Comment: @dada well that would be a completely separate problem to what this question is about, try to sort it out first and if you can't then post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) following the site posting guidelines

Comment: And note that [mcve] applies also to the command line, seeing `-g`or `-finline-limit=100000` there makes it clear you didn't try to minimize.